# LTV and NLTI capacitors and inductors' basic relations

Tags: circuit-analysis, switch-mode-power-supply, inductor, power-factor-correction, non-linear

Are the famous differential relations of inductor and capacitor true for Linear time-variant (LTV) inductors and capacitors?
How about non-linear time-invariant (NLTI) ones?

$$V_\text{L}=L\frac{dI}{dt}$$ $$I_\text{C}=C\frac{dV}{dt}$$

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the equations remain accurate, but if the values change in operation, so do the equation variables. This is why we use power-factor-correction capacitors on motors - it helps to ensure the load maintains its 'proper' reactance.

Comment: are you sure this is the answer to my question?

Comment: I'm sure it is a partial answer to your question. I can link you to a superior resource, which helps to work through more of the mathematics, but I'm not confident about the etiquette behind link-sharing. These formulas being untrue (within newtonian physics) is technically impossible. There can be complex circuit interactions which make the equations seem untrue and, over a given portion of a cycle, the equations may appear to not hold. If one factors in the power handling, reactance at different points, and other cyclic variations, a variable load holds true to these mathematic constants.